# Is there no autocomplete for volt components in vscode or is my setup broken?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-livewire, volt

I have this class in one of volt components, but I didn't get any autocomplete when referencing the chirps variable with `$this->chirps` nor did vscode show any of the methods associated with the Chirp model like `with()` and `get()`. I am wondering if this is normal or I am missing a certain vscode plugin.

if this is the norm then is there a workaround or do people just live with it?

```php
new class extends Component {
    public Collection $chirps;

    public function mount():void 
    {
        $this->chirps = Chirp::with('user')->latest()->get();
    }


}; ?>
```